# Report is being generated runs forever in IE8.0 but works with firefox

Tags: c#, reportserver

I have made a report and a simple web program in C# that is calling for that report. When I run the program it works perfect with Firefox but not in IE 8.0. In IE it´s run forever until you got this error message:**The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.**

Anybody ever had this problem before and have a solution for this.

Thanks in advance for all who reply!

The code that generate the report:
           ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;

```
        ServerReport serverReport = ReportViewer1.ServerReport;
        // Set the report server URL and report path
        serverReport.ReportServerUrl =
            new Uri("http://localhost/Reportserver");
        serverReport.ReportPath =
            "/WinLife.Accounting.Report/Report_Accountingvoucher";
        // Create the sales order number report parameter
        List<ReportParameter> paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();
        paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("Workplace", Session["WorkPlace"].ToString()));
        paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("BookkeepingYear", Session["BookkeepingYear"].ToString()));
        paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("SerialNo", Session["SerialNo"].ToString()));
        paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("DocumentType", Session["DocumentType"].ToString()));
        paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("IndentDate", Session["IndentDate"].ToString()));
        paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("AccountingVoucherCode", Session["AccountingVoucherCode"].ToString()));
        paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("UserId", Session["UserId"].ToString()));
        paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("Password", Session["Password"].ToString()));

        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

If I run the reportviewer in IE8 its looks OK. The reportserver, sql-server is installed on my machine. I run the program in Debug mode from VS2008 and I have Windows 7 installed. 
I tried to set the localhost in the trusted site but it didn´t change anything. It seems that it being stoped before it does anything in the SQL-Server. This works in Firefox.

Comment: your report is a remote report or client report?

Comment: Can you show us the code that is generating the report and give us more detail on the implementation. I'm sorry to ask but my telepathy is on the blink today, fortunately my clairvoyance isn't affected so I know it'll be better by a week on Friday.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the site to the trusted zone ? I had some similar issues and that's the way I fixed it.

Comment: If you are going to be in the internet options you may also want to try deleting your temp internet files as well, cookies, etc. Just to make sure IE starts out clean.

Comment: Tried that. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your returned data for report is very great. you can set time out value for report processing. please see the below link:

[Setting Time-out Values for Report Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155782.aspx)

Comment: It take 3 seconds for firefox to load the report.

Answer (score 0):

i was experiencing EXACTLY the same thing (including the fact that it works with FF)...

The solution is to set the "Browser Mode" to IE7...to do that follow:
1. Tools -> Developer Tools.
2. Browser Mode: -> Internet Explorer 7

btw - Microsoft sucks...